# Win7 namespace extension determine if IShellItem is file or folder

Tags: c++, windows, com, explorer

I'm developing some kind of namespace extension for Windows 7. My extension provide some application-specific stuff in context menu for all files and folder. But I want to handle files and folders in different way. Is there any way to determine if `IShellItem` providing interface object is a folder or file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [IShellItem::GetAttributes method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761138.aspx), like this:

```
SFGAOF att = 0;
if (SUCCEEDED(pItem->GetAttributes(SFGAO_FOLDER, &att))) // pItem is a IShellItem*
{
    if (att & SFGAO_FOLDER)
    {
        // it's a folder
    }
}
```